# Как поучить случайное четное или не четное число, PHP

Tags: php

нужно создать функцию которая при проверке аргумента возвращает или случайное четное или случайное нечетное нисло.

подскажите , rand(0, 100) просто случайное . а как сделать чтоб в оном случчае были четные а в другом нечетные?

в PHP.

Comment: `2x` - четные `2x + 1` - нечётные

Comment: Нечётное можно побитовым или получить: `x|1`

Answer (score 0):

```php
function evenRand($min, $max){
    return (rand(0, ($max-$min)/2)*2+$min);
}
function oddRand($min, $max){
    return (rand(0, ($max-$min)/2)*2+$min+1);
}
```

использование:

```php
oddRand(11, 19) // ранмдоное нечётное число от 11 до 19 (включительно)
evenRand(10, 20) // рандомное чётное число от 10 до 20 (включительно)
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Извиняюсь, забыл изменить

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А вообще это работает)

Comment: Попробуйте `evenRand(1, 11)` или `oddRand(2, 12)`.

Answer (score 0):

Идея `evenRandom` в том чтобы подогнать `$min` и `$max` к чётным значениям, вычислить `$n` - количество значений между ними. Случайное число генерируется для этого количества, умножается на два, прибавляется к `$min`:

```
function evenRandom($min, $max) {
    $min += $min & 1;
    $max -= $max & 1;
    $n = ($max - $min) / 2;
    return $min + 2 * rand(0, $n);
}
```

Примеры:

> ```
> even [10, 20] 14 12 10 14 18 14 10 14 20 12 12 12 12 20 20 14 18 16 18 12
> even [11, 21] 16 18 20 20 20 20 18 12 14 14 20 18 16 20 12 14 14 12 18 14
> ```

`oddRandom` отличается только способом исправления границ `$min`, `$max`:

```
function oddRandom($min, $max) {
    $min += 1 - $min & 1;
    $max -= 1 - $max & 1;
    $n = ($max - $min) / 2;
    return $min + 2 * rand(0, $n);
}
```

Примеры:

> ```
> odd [10, 20] 15 19 17 17 19 15 11 15 13 17 17 17 15 17 15 13 15 13 13 17
> odd [11, 21] 17 13 15 11 13 17 15 17 19 11 21 13 11 17 11 21 13 11 15 15
> ```

**P.S.** Я бы ещё добавил анонимные функции. Так правильнее, но сложнее:

```
function makeEvenRandom($min, $max) {
    $min += $min & 1;
    $max -= $max & 1;
    $n = ($max - $min) / 2;

    return function() use ($min, $n) {
        return $min + 2 * rand(0, $n);
    };
}

function makeOddRandom($min, $max) {
    $min += 1 - $min & 1;
    $max -= 1 - $max & 1;
    $n = ($max - $min) / 2;

    return function() use ($min, $n) {
        return $min + 2 * rand(0, $n);
    };
}
```